# SSH command doesn't work in Shell script but

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I use ssh command in Shell Script to connect to other server from ec2-user.

But ssh command does not work and the following words are displayed.

"permisson denied(puplickey)"

The authority and owner of the key used for connection are as follows.

The authority : 700
Owner of the key : ec2-user

If you know anything or have a solution please let me know:)

1.Instead of executing it with a shell script, I directly entered the ssh command I wanted to execute with a shell script and was able to connect successfully

2.I echoed the ssh command to be executed in the shell script and checked for spelling mistakes in the command to be executed. no problem

Comment: 644, not 700. Cheatsheet: ~/.ssh: 700, public key: 644, private key: 600, authorized_keys: 644.

Comment: Captain Nitpick checking in: ~/.ssh can be 755.